# Clash of Clans Algorithm for random trees/bushes

Tags: clash-of-clans

How is it determined when and how many trees/bushes/plants/Gem Boxes spawn in your plot?

Is there variables it depends on (like your Town Hall level, amount of workers)? Is it based solely on the time that passes? Does the available space on your plot play a role?

I am really curious about this, and this would definitely influence my decisions going forward, consider the potential gain in gems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Obstacles):

> Vegetation **respawns at a rate of one item per eight hours**, except if all the spaces in your village are totally filled. Furthermore, an obstacle will only spawn if there is a one tile buffer zone between the spaces in which it will spawn and another building or obstacle.

So it doesn't depend on anything, just time that passes

Comment: Does this include Gem Boxes?

Comment: I think it's fixed too. But keep in mind that: "An obstacle cannot spawn directly next to building because there always has to be at least one field in between." [source](http://www.allclash.com/improve-obstacle-spawn-rate-for-more-gems/)

Comment: gem boxes is semi random